# How to add entities with foreign keys that I dont have a reference to

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entity classes:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; } // Foreign key
}
```

and 3 repo methods:

```
    public async Task AddUserAsync(string userId)
    {
        await _context.Users.AddAsync(new User { Id = userId });
    }

    public async Task AddProfileAsync(string userId, string name)
    {
        await _context.Profiles.AddAsync(new Profile
        {
            Name = userId,
            User = // What do I put here?
        });
    }

    // Service decides when to save changes
    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

How do I specify the foreign key? I tried a few things but I get exceptions related to entity tracking.

Comment: The `Profile` entity should have a `UserId` property that acts as the foriegn key to the `User` table then you'd just set it instead of the `User` navigation property.

Comment: @juharr So you are saying I shouldn't use navigation properties or that I should have both?

Comment: You should have both.  And EF will handle if you only set one.